# Method not found in entity Paginator from doctrine bundle

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, paginator

I'm trying to clean up some code done in a messy way and right now I'm having trouble with doctrine's paginator. 
When I'm accessing a page that handle paginator in order to show all different articles of my blog I'm getting this error:

> Neither the property "id" nor one of the methods "id()", "getid()"/"isid()"/"hasid()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Pagination\Paginator".

In doctrine vendor bundle those methods are not set but my entity have them and I know that it is forbidden to edit a vendor file. I'm missing something because I don't know if I should extend my paginator entity and add those missing methods or is there a little bit more to do ?

I just started symfony and I know that my bases are not enough to understand it all by myself.

Thank you very much for you time and attention.

Here is my Article controller for route category:

```
 /**
     * @Route("/categorie/{id}", name="categorie")
     *
     * @param Request                       $request
     * @param Helper                        $helper
     * @param AuthorizationCheckerInterface $authChecker
     * @param DocumentCategory              $categorie
     * @param TwitterService                $twitterService
     *
     * @return RedirectResponse|Response
     */
    public function categorie(
        Request $request,
        Helper $helper,
        AuthorizationCheckerInterface $authChecker,
        DocumentCategory $categorie,
        TwitterService $twitterService
    ) {
        if (!$authChecker->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')
            && !$authChecker->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED')) {
            return $this->redirectToRoute('login');
        }
        $page = (int) ($request->get('page'));
        if (0 === $page) {
            $page = 1;
        }

        $userType = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('App:User')
            ->getManagerExpertCollabo($this->getUser());

        $articleAlaUneListe = [];

        $articleIdListe = $helper->getArticleIdAuth($authChecker);

        $articleListe = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('App:Document')
            ->getPage(
                self::ITEM_PER_PAGE * ($page - 1),
                self::ITEM_PER_PAGE,
                'document.dateCreated',
                'DESC',
                '(documentCategory.id = \''.$categorie->getId().'\' and '.$helper->baseRequestArticle().')',
                7,
                [],
                $articleIdListe
            );
        [$articlePopulaireListe, $categorieListe, $totalPage] = $this->getPopularArticleList(
            $articleListe,
            $helper,
            $articleIdListe
        );

        $articlesList->getDocuments();
        $feedData = $twitterService->getTwitterFeed();

        return $this->render('article/list.html.twig', [
                'pageClass' => 'backoffice withFooterLarge dashboard',
                'totalPage' => $totalPage,
                'page' => $page,
                'feedData' => $feedData,
                'categorieListe' => $categorieListe,
                'categorie' => $categorie,
                'articleAlaUneListe' => $articleAlaUneListe,
                'articlePopulaireListe' => $articlePopulaireListe,
                'articleListe' => $articleListe, ]);
    }
```

Here is the document entity for categories field:

```
 /**
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="ht_lk_document_category"),
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\DocumentCategory", inversedBy="documents")
     */
    private $categories;

 /**
     * @return Collection|array<DocumentCategory>
     */
    public function getCategories(): Collection
    {
        return $this->categories;
    }

    public function setCategories($category): self
    {
        $this->categories = $category;

        return $this;
    }
```

Here is the DocumentCategory entity :

```
/**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Document", mappedBy="categories")
     */
    private $documents;

/**
     * @return Collection|Document[]
     */
    public function getDocuments(): Collection
    {
        return $this->documents;
    }
```

Here is the Document Repository :

```
public function getPage($first_result, $max_results, $orderby, $direction, $criteria, $documentType = null, $searchWordArray = [], $articleIdListe = '')
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('docArticle');
    $qb->select('docArticle')
    ->addSelect('documentCategory', 'documentCategory')
    ->addSelect('user', 'user')
    /*
    if(sizeof($searchWordArray) > 0){
        $fieldIndice = 1;
        foreach($searchWordArray as $searchWord){
            $qb->andWhere('(document.name_fr LIKE ?'.$fieldIndice.' or document.name_en LIKE ?'.$fieldIndice.' or document.content_fr LIKE ?'.$fieldIndice.' or document.content_en LIKE ?'.$fieldIndice.')');
            $qb->setParameter($fieldIndice++, '%'.$searchWord.'%');
        }
    } */
    ->leftJoin('docArticle.categories', 'documentCategory')
    ->leftJoin('docArticle.author', 'user')
    ->setFirstResult($first_result)
    ->setMaxResults($max_results);
    if (!empty($criteria)) {
        $qb->where('('.$criteria.')');
    }
    if (!empty($orderby)) {
        $qb->orderBy($orderby, $direction);
    }
    $pag = new Paginator($qb->getQuery());
    $qb->setFirstResult(0);
    $qb->setMaxResults(PHP_INT_MAX);
    $sql = $qb->getQuery()->getSql();
    if ('()' !== $articleIdListe) {
        $qb->where('(docArticle.id IN '.$articleIdListe);
    }
    $compte = \count($qb->getQuery()->getScalarResult());

    return ['page' => $pag, 'compte' => $compte];
}
```

And finally here is the Document Category Repository :

```
/**
 * @param $first_result
 * @param $max_results
 * @param $orderby
 * @param $direction
 * @param $criteria
 * @param int|null $documentType
 * @param array    $searchWordArray
 * @param string   $articleIdListe
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function getPage(
    $first_result,
    $max_results,
    $orderby,
    $direction,
    $criteria,
    $documentType = null,
    $searchWordArray = [],
    $articleIdListe = ''
) {
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('document');
    $qb->select('document')
    ->addSelect('documentCategory', 'documentCategory')
    ->addSelect('user', 'user')
    ->addSelect('documentType', 'documentType');
    if (\count($searchWordArray) > 0) {
        $fieldIndice = 1;
        foreach ($searchWordArray as $searchWord) {
            $qb->andWhere(
                '('
                .'document.name_fr LIKE ?'.$fieldIndice
                .' or document.name_en LIKE ?'.$fieldIndice
                .' or document.content_fr LIKE ?'.$fieldIndice
                .' or document.content_en LIKE ?'.$fieldIndice
                .')'
            );
            $qb->setParameter($fieldIndice++, '%'.$searchWord.'%');
        }
    }
    if ($documentType) {
        if (\mb_strlen($articleIdListe) > 3) {
            $qb->andWhere('(documentType.id = :documentType OR document.id IN '.$articleIdListe.')')
                ->setParameter('documentType', $documentType);
        } else {
            $qb->andWhere('(documentType.id = :documentType)')
                ->setParameter('documentType', $documentType);
        }
    }
    $qb->leftJoin('document.categories', 'documentCategory')
    ->leftJoin('document.documentType', 'documentType')
    ->leftJoin('document.author', 'user')
    ->setFirstResult($first_result)
    ->setMaxResults($max_results)
    ->andWhere('document.documentType<>6');
    if (!empty($criteria)) {
        $qb->andWhere('('.$criteria.')');
    }
    if (!empty($orderby)) {
        $qb->orderBy($orderby, $direction);
    }
    $sql = $qb->getQuery()->getSql();

    $pag = new Paginator($qb->getQuery());
    dump($pag);
    $qb->setFirstResult(0);
    $qb->setMaxResults(PHP_INT_MAX);
    $sql = $qb->getQuery()->getSql();

    $compte = \count($qb->getQuery()->getScalarResult());

    return ['page' => $pag, 'compte' => $compte];
}

/**
 * @param int|null $documentType
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function getArticleIdList($documentType = null)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('document');
    $qb->select('document.id');
    if ($documentType) {
        $qb->where('(document.documentType = :documentType)')
            ->setParameter('documentType', $documentType);
    }
    $compte = $qb->getQuery()->getScalarResult();

    return $compte;
}
```

(I deleted all unnecessary method for this question)

Comment: Your error is typically a Twig error. You should check your templates to see if you try to get the id of your entity on a Paginator instance instead of on a Document instance.

Comment: But I'm sending the parameters to twig so there should be an paginator instance in my controller no ?

Comment: Yes, your repositories methods seems to return a Paginator instance. I can't tell you more without see them. Maybe you should edit your questions with them or try to find by ourself with this informations

Comment: I've updated the code, I really don't understand how to get into my entity methods as the paginator object is overriding the entity object. I've created a simple query in order to get my articles from the category, this worked but when I'm adding some verification field it sends me the error

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to the entity class from which you want to show data:

```
public function getId(): ?string
{
   return $this->id;
}
```

Or
if you do not want the property "id" to be displayed in the view, comment out or delete the lines of code in your Twig template for the entity in question. For example, delete

```
<td>{{ Category.id }}</td>
```